# Using a list item to edit a list

Tags: rust

I am doing some modifications of the [dining philosophers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/dining-philosophers.html) problem from the Rust book.

In the book, they create all the philosophers manually, with the last one having his left and right hand switched. I did this programmatically (using a for loop that I pushed philosophers onto) and now I want to modify the final philosopher.

**This is what I want to do**

```
// make the last philosopher left handed (switch forks)
let p = &philosophers[length - 1];
philosophers[length - 1] = Philosopher{left: p.right, right: p.left, name: p.name.clone()};
// error: cannot move out of indexed content [E0507]
```

**This is what I have to do**

```
philosophers[length - 1] = Philosopher{
   left: philosophers[length - 1].right, 
   right: philosophers[length - 1].left, 
   name: philosophers[length -1].name.clone(),
};
```

The first example doesn't compile, and I can't find a way to get it compile without doing something like `let p = philosophers[length - 1].clone()` -- which completely copies the data! (not really what I want).

Is there a way to do this more rustily?

Comment: I have gone ahead and removed the answer from the question; if I deleted some content that you wish to retrieve (for example, to post your own answer if you think your code is better than Lukas') then you can click on "edited X time ago" which links to the [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34627695/revisions) for your question and grab all you want from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you can't change something you are currently borrowing. You *could* clone it -- you are already cloning the `name` field anyway and `left` and `right` are only `usize`.

Assuming your structure contains more and bigger data, cloning is not an option. There are multiple possible solutions in that case. You could use a `Vec` instead of an ordinary array: first create all 4 normal philosophers and then `push` the last one. Or you can use [`std::mem::swap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html) to swap `left` and `right`:

```
std::mem::swap(&mut philosophers[length - 1].left, &mut philosophers[length - 1].right);
```

Comment: Gettin `error: cannot borrow immutable field 'p.left' as mutable`. How do I make the item in the list mutable? My current declartion is `let mut philosophers: Vec<Philosopher> = vec![];`. Trying to put `mut` in varous places didn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Everything works now thanks to your edit. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

This example is so short that IMHO the original solution (without the loop) is more expressive. But if you want to change the last philosopher, you can do this:

```
let p = &mut philosophers[length - 1];
let left = p.left;
let right = p.right;
p.left = right;
p.right = left;
```

You will operate on a reference of the last philosopher directly. This way, you don't need to clone his/her name, just swap the fork ids.

Comment: this will also copy the data. I was trying to understand a rusty way to do this without copying the data. Obviously in this simple example, copying a few uints isn't a problem :)